# Boot Windows 10 in UEFI Mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios

I am installing windows 10 within my computer and for this I have created bootable USB drive for Windows 10 using Rufus software.

I have 256GB SSD in which I am doing clean install of Windows 10 OS. During windows 10 installation process, after files getting copied to SSD, it's time to perform installation through SSD and computer is restarted for this.

But then after restart, its started giving this kind of error message:
[image]

I don't know what to do for this! I have changed different settings of BIOS but result was not changed for me.

This is my system BIOS settings:
[image]

Please give me a suggestion for this so I can complete my Windows 10 installation.

Comment: “Other PCI devices” shouldn’t be set to **Legacy**, Akeo suspicion is correct. Additionally, once Windows has copied its files, you don’t need the installer disk.

Answer (score 1):

I think the last option applies to you: Your `Boot Option #1` seems to be set to **Legacy** boot of the newly installed Windows, which means that, since you installed Windows in UEFI mode, `Boot Option #1` will be skipped but your system may still attempt to boot the next media (your USB drive) in Legacy mode, hence the message you see.

So, the first thing you should do, once the Windows installer has finished copying the files onto your SSD is **remove** the USB media, as it is no longer needed.

Then you need to figure out how to ensure that `Boot Option #1` says something like `UEFI: Ant Esports 690 NEO SATA 25` instead of `P0: Ant Esports 690 NEO SATA 25` (assuming that this is your SSD drive) as the part before the colon usually indicates whether your computer will attempt to boot it in Legacy or UEFI mode, and I am pretty confident, given your description, that you installed Windows in UEFI mode.

Unfortunately however, there's no universal way to figure out how you may be able to alter these options: it all depends on the specific manufacturer of your computer/UEFI firmware. So you may have to figure out what exactly you need to do so that your SATA devices try to boot in UEFI mode first, instead of Legacy mode first.

Comment: Thank you sir for your proper explanation. Let me share more details. Basically BIOS system get corrupted few days ago so with my local computer hardware person I have installed new BIOS system within my PC. Compare to before he installed different version of BIOS. May be this is the reason for Legacy partition scheme become default?

Comment: May I replace with previous version of BIOS? because within that I was using the same USB drive to install Windows 10

Comment: It's unlikely that changing your BIOS version will do much when the most likely problem is that your BIOS __settings__ (which are independent of the version you use) were reset, and that these default settings appear to have SATA devices boot in Legacy mode instead of UEFI mode. You need to check your computer/motherboard manual to find out how you can change the settings so that UEFI boot is prioritized over Legacy boot for SATA devices

Comment: Amazing information sir, let me do some research on this and coming back you with some new information. Motherboard Full name - Gigabyte GA-H110M-S2

Comment: I have contacted Gigabyte support for this purpose.